# Display sound name when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a button that when pressed it will play a random sound. I would like to be able to have it display a certain text depending on what sound is being played. I need some help as I'm rather new to this stuff.

Here's the html

```
<a href="#" onclick="mySounds()" id="soundbutton" class="button button1"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="meme.js"></script></div>
```

Here's the Javascript

```
var sounds = ["Titanic.mp3",
"biggiecheese.mp3",
"mcscuseme.mp3",
"orgasm.mp3",
"broccoli.mp3",
"crab.mp3",
"sniffing.mp3",
"criminal.mp3",
"suicidal.mp3",
"arrow.mp3",
"r2d2.mp3",
"carlwheezer.mp3",
"banana.mp3",
"blaster.mp3"


/*".mp3",*/

];

var sound;

//function used to create a random number
function generateRandomNumber(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function playSound() {
  //create a random number and assign to x
  var x = generateRandomNumber(sounds.length - 1);
  var soundSrc = sounds[x];
  //create a new instance of the audio object
  if (sound) {
      sound.pause();
  } else {
  sound = new Audio();
  }
  sound.src = soundSrc;
  //play the sound
  sound.play();
}

document.getElementById('soundbutton').addEventListener('click', playSound);
```

Comment: You have an event for "onclick" as well as adding an event listener, which one are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just set any element with the sound name on the onClick listener.

```
<span id='myspan'></span>
<script>
    function playSound() {
      ...
      document.getElementById('myspan').innerHTML = sound.src;
    }
</script>
```

Also, as Brimstone stated, you don't need the last line, because the link is bound to the listener in the definition.

```
document.getElementById('soundbutton').addEventListener('click', playSound);
```